# way to create wiki app on android from preexisting wiki

Tags: android, wiki

I'm trying to make a android app for a wiki I created using mediawiki. However, I don't know what the best method would be. Should I make a webview for my wiki or is there a better way to do it?
Thanks

Comment: Why a native app? MediaWiki is web app...why not just use the device's web browser?

Comment: It didn't mean a native app. I'm just a beginner  and I don't know if their is anything other then web view  to make this an app.

Comment: Also do you know  if  mediawiki has a mobile based website platform

Comment: Your question isn't clear. An android app to do what, with your Mediawiki site?